# Loop. Determine if either value exists

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I have a quick powershell syntax question. I have following loop in powershell. I would like to know which value exists (which is easy). I can use either "Read" or "Visitor" to assign permission. I can do 2 if statements but if there is a smarter way i would rather use that.

```
if(($listRA.Member.Name) -ne $authUsers)
{
    foreach($spRoleDefinition in $rc)
    {
        if(($spRoleDefinition.Name -eq "Read") -OR ($spRoleDefinition.Name -eq "SP Visitor"))
        {
            Need to determine which one exists
            Adding a user code....
            write-host $spRoleDefinition.Name
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use a `switch` statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847750.aspx):

```
if(($listRA.Member.Name) -ne $authUsers)
{
    foreach($spRoleDefinition in $rc)
    {
        switch($spRoleDefinition.Name)
        {
            'Read' {
                # do Read stuff
                break;
            }

            'SP Visitor' {
                # do SP Visitor stuff
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian for the tip. I appreciated it.

Comment: What if both exists. Because if both exists then I will using SP Visitor to add permission. If only Read exists then I will use Read. The code is same for read and sp visitor which is adding user with that permission level

Comment: @NinjaCowgirl your `if` statement uses `-eq` so if the value can somehow be both, then that condition would have never satisfied your `if` statement. What data type is `$spRoleDefinition.Name`? What are the possible values?

Comment: string. and possible values are Read, SP Visitor, Contribute, Full, etc.

Comment: @NinjaCowgirl If the variable is string and the possible values are what you said they are, then both can't co-exist for same `$spRoleDefinition`. They can co-exist if the datatype is `String[]` i.e. an array.

Comment: yes, my bad. it's string array that's why I am doing for each.

Comment: I added break and that seemed to do the job. Thanks BrianST